# Is more than 1 update per minute possible for a watchface in android wear in ambient mode?

Tags: android, wear-os

Trying to develop a watchface for android wear that really needs to be updated when in ambient mode twice per minute.

Scenario is that I help out in school exams and the time in these exams is taken from the big clock at the front of the room not what my watch says the time is. Also the time needs to be accurate to just about the second for stopping exams, giving remaining time announcements, etc. Trying to code a watch face that allows me to store the offset between 'real time' and 'exam time' so I can show both on the watch with 'real time' being displayed smaller and the main displayed time being 'exam time'.

Problem is that in ambient mode the watch face is only updated once per minute when 'real time' starts a new minute so the exam time can have moved well into the next minute without the time being updated so when the watch comes out of ambient mode the time can be noticeably different. so, for example, in ambient it could say 12:00 but when woken it could easily say 12:01:50 if 'real time' crosses the minute boundary just before 'exam time' does.

Once I know the offset of 'exam time' from 'real time' I can easily calculate when in each minute of real time the 'exam time' crosses the minute boundary and so a redrawn is needed but I cannot find any details about if its possibly just on the watch itself of scheduling the needed additional refreshes of the ambient display.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do additional updates using AlarmManager but, in general, it is really preferred if you could stick to 1 update per minute frequency to preserve battery